# php: check pressed button on keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following structure in my page:
`page.php`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page title</title>
        <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function search(value){
                window.location.href="page.php?search=" + value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if(!empty($_GET['search'])){
                //SQL-statement with WHERE column LIKE $_GET['search']
            } else {
                //Other SQL-statement without WHERE column LIKE $_GET['search']
            }
        ?>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <input type="text" onKeyUp="search(this.value);" 
               value="<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>">
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can read, it's important, when a `spacebar` is pressed, it puts an `_` in the `$_GET['search']` and in my `input`-field, it's a `&nsbp;`

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: When I hit the spacebar, I need to get a _ in the value

Comment: Before update the query string you may need to replace the required value.

Comment: Use `$.ajax`rather to redirect on same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` is `' '` (a single space) and
`window.location.href="page.php?search=" + value;`
will be URL encoded, so spaces are turned into `&nbsp;` (URL entities)

You'll have to `urldecode($_GET['search']);` to turn it back into a space character. (https://www.php.net/urldecode)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a replace like this:

```
var new_string = old_str.replace("&nbsp;", "_");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])){
         $q=urldecode($_GET['search']);// use it in your query
         //SQL-statement with WHERE column LIKE $_GET['search']
    } else {
        //Other SQL-statement without WHERE column LIKE $_GET['search']
    }
?>
```

Read [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)